# OpenGL color interpolation using a cosine function?

Tags: opengl, colors, glsl, interpolation

I want to render a quad, I want one side of the quad to be white and the other to be black. Instead of a simple linear color interpolation for the pixels between, I need for it to mimic a cosine function.

What is a good way to approach this?

Comment: Do you have shader support for your versions of GL?

Comment: yes there is GLSL support, i have not used custom shaders before. Any recommendations for a good GLSL tutorial?

Comment: These are pretty good to begin with. http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in a fragment shader. I.e.:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( cos( in_TexCoord.x ) ), 1.0 );
```

You can tune the exact values of amplitude and phase as you like for every color channel.